# Line breaks causing php bugs?

Tags: php, newline

I have a php form process script that wasn't saving correctly on our live or test severs but was working in my local test environment. I committed some trivial changes to the file and it started processing correctly. I then reverted those changes and thing still worked correctly.

I'm wondering if there was possibly some line breaks / newlines or other hidden characters that were in there causing the problem. Has anyone else experienced anything like this?

Comment: If your syntax is correct newlines shouldn't be an issue.  Check the file permissions and ensure they are readable by the webserver -- i've been caught offguard by that before.

Comment: Can you clarify "wasn't saving correctly"?

Comment: What type of errors was causes by "incorrect" version of the file?

Comment: Parts of the form would save as expected, but others wouldn't. No errors or warnings were thrown. There was one object in particular that would save if certain values were sent, but wouldn't save otherwise.

Comment: Are you using version control such as SVN to store your php code?

Comment: I am his co-worker. Yes, we are using SVN.

Answer (score 1):

My first thoughts would go for the following things to check:

- If you get somekind of header already sent errors check for [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)-Bytes or other invisible char at the start of your script
- Are you using non-englisch characters for html/form names or php variables check the encoding of all files. It must be the the same everywhere
- Google arround for php lineending-settings. A while ago I heard about somethings that could occour if lineendings were wrong.

**EDIT:** Otherwise it would be helpfull if you give us some example code.

Comment: +1 for Byte-Order Mark; can be a real pain since PHP will evaluate it as output.

Answer (score 0):

You might have had a hidden character before your opening `<?php` tag.

If you were doing any header manipulation or `session_start()` it will fail because if `<?php` isn't the first thing in the file then the server will start it's response.

- [PHP header function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)
- [session_start()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)

You should check your php error logs.